# How can i get some returns from this function in Python?

Tags: python

this is the class that I've written but it doesn't returns me nothing on the python's terminal, but if i write loose out the class it returns what it should, why?
Either if I put some print it doesn't give me back nothing.
Anyway I want to have back  `portfolio_initial_amount` and `current_price` variables.
I'm using some apis from coinmarketcap.
Here the code

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint
from main import *

'''Percentage variation for first 20 cryptocurrencies for capitalization in the last 24 hours'''

class Variation_in_24h:
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest'

        self.params = {
            'start':'1',
            'limit':'100',
            'convert':'USD',
            'sort':'market_cap',
            'sort_dir':'desc'
        }

        self.headers = {
            'Accepts':'applications/json',
            'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY':'b8ee0ea1-ae9b-44ab-9132-02e6e5430eb1'
        }


    def getData(self):
        r = requests.get(url=self.url, headers=self.headers, params=self.params).json()
        current_price = []
        currencies_variation = []
        for currency in r['data']:
            current_price.append(
            currency['quote']['USD']['price']
            ) and currencies_variation.append(
            currency['quote']['USD']['percent_change_24h']
            )

        portfolio_initial_amount = (sum(current_price[:20]))
        twenty_currencies_variation = (sum(currencies_variation[:20]))
        average_variation = (twenty_currencies_variation/20)

        current_price = ((portfolio_initial_amount * average_variation) / 100.0) + portfolio_initial_amount

        current_price = str(current_price)
        portfolio_initial_amount = str(portfolio_initial_amount)
        return ("Portfolio\'s initial amount, for the first 20 cryptocurrencies, was " + portfolio_initial_amount, "The current price of your portfolio is " + current_price)
```

Comment: Do you ever create an instantiation of that class?

Comment: I mean he king of has a point. Since he has learned about functions, the first thing any teacher says is to use the function. Similarly, they do the same for classes. Which could make me question he wrote it. However, he probably did, just made a silly mistake and came here asking for help. @DeepSpace good job on catching that, and Jack Lihammers, you may have a point, but that comment wasn't needed. This comment wasn't needed as well, but oh well

Answer (score 0):

As one of the comments pointed out, constructors are defined by saying

```
def __init__
```

Using two underscores, not one as you've done.

```
def _init_
```

But also your return statement within the function probably doesn't work as you intended.

```
return ("Portfolio\'s initial amount, for the first 20 cryptocurrencies, was " + portfolio_initial_amount) and ("The current price of your portfolio is " + current_price)
```

^ this code returns only the second value, or nothing at all. If you want to return multiple strings then it would make it

```
return ("Portfolio\'s initial amount, for the first 20 cryptocurrencies, was " + portfolio_initial_amount, "The current price of your portfolio is " + current_price)
```

Or you could just make it a single return string

```
return "Portfolio\'s initial amount, for the first 20 cryptocurrencies, was " + portfolio_initial_amount + " The current price of your portfolio is " + current_price
```